# Objective C Route/Path with array of buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, path, grid

I'm practically new to Objective C and iOS Dev and I need to make an app that records a "route" or "path" (like the dot lock protection app). So I thought in buttons pressed while dragging, enabling all the direct neighbors (right, left, up, down). I have started coding but I dont know if I'm in the right direction and **How can I implement a dragging press, so that the user don't have to press each button, but trace a path with it's finger**

viewController.m

(void)viewDidLoad

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
for (int y=0; y < 9; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(20 + 30 * x, 20 + 30 * y, 30, 30);
        unsigned buttonNumber = y * 9 + x + 1;
        button.tag = buttonNumber;

        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", buttonNumber] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"!"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
        [self.view addSubview: button];
    }
}
```

This code (adapted from Jorge's in my other post) generates a 9x9 button grid with unique tag.

And the respective action method,

(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button

```
if(first){

    for (int y=0; y < 9; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            unsigned buttonNumber = y * 9 + x + 1;
            UIButton *auxButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:buttonNumber];

            if ((auxButton.tag != (button.tag + 1)) || (auxButton.tag != (button.tag - 1)) || (buttonNumber != (button.tag + 9)) || (buttonNumber != (button.tag - 9)) || (buttonNumber != button.tag )){

                auxButton.enabled = FALSE;

            }
        }
    }else{ 
//not implemented yet
}
```

What I did here was: initially all buttons are enabled, but when the first one is pressed it will disable all the buttons except for the direct neighbors (l,r,u,d).

My if(condition) is not working with OR conditions (||), so all buttons are disabled, but if I only use one condition, say if(auxButton.tag != button.tag + 1), it works.

What could be wrong in here?
How can I implement that a path traced with the touch presses all the buttons it passes by?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "How can I implement that a path traced with the touch presses all the buttons it passes by?" So can you please give more clarifications please if my answer below is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, what I mean is: what can I do for that several buttons are pressed with only one finger press and while pressed it is moved through the screen.

Comment: Have you tested the solution I provided below? Try the code in the for loop to see if the correct buttons are enabled/disabled when you press a button (as a normal button). If it doesn't work, tell me what's wrong, maybe I can help. Then try to change **UIControlEventTouchUpInside** by **UIControlEventTouchDragInside**, **UIControlEventTouchDragEnter** or another similar event.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and it works as expected. I'll use it as part of my code.
I've tried with the different UIControlEvents and its not working as I expected, maybe because of the simulator, I'll test some other stuff I have in mind and post it back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable all the buttons except `button` and its neighbors you can do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
    UIButton *other = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i+1];
    if (other != button) {
        int deltaRow = abs((button.tag-1)%9 - (other.tag-1)%9);
        int deltaColumn = abs((button.tag-1)/9 - (other.tag-1)/9);
        other.enabled = (deltaRow == 0 && deltaColumn == 1) // same row, successive columns
                      ||(deltaRow == 1 && deltaColumn == 0) // same column, successive rows
    }
}
```

Remove the test `(other != button)` if you want button to be disabled too.

Also check if you want use `UIControlEventTouchDragInside` or `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter` instead of `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. See documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events).